# How do I remove duplicated words and comma's from my input when answering in lines 11-20 for my Python 3 code? No suggestions works at all for mine

Tags: python

How do I remove every duplicated word and comma from my code on lines 11-20 in my code below? I have tried everyone's suggestions and answers for days of attempting but nobody's code works for mine! Please help me!

If I answer the input with 1 coffee type like this, "Expresso" I get "You have selected a Expresso!", this is correct. If I answer the input with 2 or more coffee types like this, "Expresso Latte Cappuccino Mocha Frappuccino" I get "You have selected Expresso, Latte, Cappuccino, Mocha and a Frappuccino!" this is correct.

But if I answer the input with 2 or more coffee types like this, "Expresso, Latte, Cappuccino, Mocha and a Frappuccino" I get "Expresso,, Latte,, Cappuccino,, Mocha,, And and a Frappuccino!" this is wrong!

Output I want: "You have selected Expresso, Latte, Cappuccino, Mocha and a Frappuccino!"

Regardless if I type "and" "," to answer the input, I want the same correct output.

My code below

```
company_name = "Daniel's Coffee"

greeting_introduction = "\nHello! Welcome to "

print(greeting_introduction + company_name + "!")

first_name = input("\nCan I start off with your first name?\n\n")

print("\nThank you," + " " + first_name.capitalize() + "!")

order = input("\n" + first_name.capitalize() + "," " " + "What type of Coffee would you 
like today?\n\n" +
          "\n" .join(["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha", "Frappuccino"]) + 
"\n\n")

order = order.lower().split()
union = " and a " if len(order) > 1 else ""
plural = "" if len(order) > 1 else ""
print("\nYou have selected a" + " " + ", " .join(order[:-1]).title() + union + plural + 
order[-1].title() + "!")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is well known for its ability to deal with various scenarios and string handling, and in this case you can resolve the problem of repetition of commas and the "and a" term with the string.replace method, removing the excess commas and the term "and a" before parsing it. Here's some code to sort out the problem of yours:

```
company_name = "Daniel's Coffee"

greeting_introduction = "\nHello! Welcome to "

print(greeting_introduction + company_name + "!")

first_name = input("\nCan I start off with your first name?\n\n")

print("\nThank you," + " " + first_name.capitalize() + "!")

order = input("\n" + first_name.capitalize() + "," " " + "What type of Coffee would you like today?\n\n" +
  "\n" .join(["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha", "Frappuccino"]) + "\n\n")

#Solving the repetition of "and a"
order = order.replace("and a", "")
order = order.replace("and", "")
order = order.replace(",", "")
order = order.lower().split()

union = " and a " if len(order) > 1 else ""

plural = "" if len(order) > 1 else ""

print("\nYou have selected a" + " " + ", " .join(order[:-1]).title() + union + plural +
order[-1].title() + "!"
```

Comment: @DanielStoica if your issue has been resolved by this answer, consider marking it as accepted.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `plural = "s" if len(order) > 1 else ""`?

Comment: Oh yeah it should, my bad!

Answer (score 0):

```
...
order = input("\n" + first_name.capitalize() + "," " " + "What type of Coffee would you 
like today?\n\n" +
          "\n" .join(["Expresso", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Mocha", "Frappuccino"]) + 
"\n\n")

order = order.replace(",", " ").replace("and", " ")
```

Then, to remove duplicates you can just do

```
...
```

Just replace all `,` or `and` with a space.

Inputing

```
Expresso and Latte, Cappuccino Mocha
```

I got

```
You have selected a Expresso, Latte, Cappuccino and a Mocha!
```

Edit.:

To remove duplicates you can do the following

```
order = list(set(order.lower().split()))
```

Comment: But what if the customer puts in the same exact input to answer with "and" or ","? I want to force the code to only give me the correct input.

Comment: I got "You have selected a And, Expresso and a Latte!" The And and , still didn't dissapear.